# Cryptography Notion - Diffie-Hellmann

Tags: math, cryptography, theory, proof, diffie-hellman

I am currently working on a problem in cryptography that goes like this:
Game 1: Adversary is given g1,g2 and h. The given h can either be g1g2 or totally random action g3. (by action i mean an operation applied to an element). This adversary can distinguish which h is being used.
Game 2: the adversary is given g1 and h. This h is either g1g1 or g2 totally random. This adversary needs to use the adversary from game1 to gain advantage in guessing correctly.

Any idea how to go about it?